# Lodash nested forEach with if statement creating JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I am trying to create a JSON object using the properties of another. I am using a series of nested for loops an trying to discover the contents of each `field.name` and then create a new object `job.id` and assign the value of `field.data`. This is what I have so far;

```
_.forEach(records, function(record) {
    _.forEach(record.field, function(field) {
        if(field.name === "ID") {
            job.id = field.data;
        }
        if(field.name === "JobNumber") {
            job.job_number = field.data;
        }
        jobs.push(job);
    });
});
output.push(jobs.concat());
```

However my output is as follows

```
{
    "id": "a-long-job-id",
    "job_number": "fourcharacterjobnumber"
},
{
    "id": "sameasabove",
    "job_number": "sameasabove"
},
{
    "id": "sameasabove",
    "job_number": "sameasabove"
}, ...
```

What seems to happening is the array is not being updated, so any help with this would be so greatly appreciated.

**Note** I am looking to make this into a function so that a configuration object would be passed in and where there is `if(field.name === "ID")`, I would hope to use `if(field.name === config[field.name])`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try adding `var job={};` just before the first `if`

Comment: please add input data, and desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that code that you have shown it seems that you are using the same job object in all the iterations. Because of this there is only 1 job object that is getting updated and getting pushed to jobs array in all iterations. Try creating a new job object and pushing it to jobs array in the outer loop.

I assume you have defined jobs array before first forEach.

```
_.forEach(records, function(record) {
    var job = {}; // new object
    _.forEach(record.field, function(field) {
        if(field.name === "ID") {
            job.id = field.data;
        }
        if(field.name === "JobNumber") {
            job.job_number = field.data;
        }
    });
    jobs.push(job); // moved out
});
output.push(jobs.concat());
```

Comment: Yes that's right, jobs and output are defined before the first forEach.